# __main__.Person object at 0x02F47148

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

У меня проблема, при запуске кода, выводит ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Person:
    name: str
    surname: str
    age: int


user = Person()
user.name = "John"
user.surname = "Doe"
user.age = 30

print(user)
```

Comment: Это не ошибка. Что Вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: окей, но тогда почему не выводит данные ?

Comment: Выводит. Вам вывело, что инстанс класса `Person` находится в `__main__` модуле по такому-то адресу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить функцию, которая будет позволять печатать данные в виде строки:

```
class Person:
    name: str
    surname: str
    age: int

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'Name: {self.name}, '
                f'Surname:{self.surname}, '
                f'Age: {self.age}')


user = Person()
user.name = "John"
user.surname = "Doe"
user.age = 30

print(user)
```

Name: John, Surname:Doe, Age: 30

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print(user.name)
John
>>> print(user.surname)
Doe
>>> print(user.age)
30
```